# The work-energy theorem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, work, potential-energy

Well here's the question.

From some previous excercises we know that from 
\begin{align}
A&=\int F\;ds,\\
 &=\int ma\;ds,   &&(F=ma)\\
 &=\int m \frac{dv}{dt}\;ds, &&(a=dv/dt)\\
 &=m \int_{v_1}^{v_2}v\; dv,\\
 &=m  \frac{v_2^2}{2}-m  \frac{v_1^2}{2},\\
 &=W_2-W_1,   &&(W_i=\frac12mv_i^2)\\
 &=\Delta W.
\end{align}
Meanwhile for potential energy we have the shown figure 
\begin{align}
A&= \int m a\;ds,\\
 &= \int m \frac{dv}{dt}\;ds,
\end{align}
Here the professor did something like:
$$ds \times \cos \alpha =-dh$$
and then the equation goes 
\begin{align}
A&=- \int m \frac{dv}{dt}\;dh,\\
 &=- \int m v \;dv,\\
 &=-m \int v \text{ }dv
\end{align}
and up to

$$A=-\Delta W_p$$

Now what I'd like to understand from you is one logic explanation for

$$ds \times \cos \alpha=-dh$$

I'd be very grateful!
[image]

Comment: Could you help to specify the problem more? For example, how is $F$ defined? Is this a 2D problem? If 2D, is $F$ a force acting tangential to the path of motion? If $F$ doesn't, then should there not be any vector notation? What exactly do all the variables represent, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The height $h$ is probably the vertical displacement pointing downwards. Therefore:
$$
h = \left(-\mathbf{\hat j}\right)\cdot\mathbf s = -|\mathbf{\hat j}||\mathbf s|\cos\alpha = -s\cos\alpha
$$

Now we can derive:
$$
\frac{dh}{ds} = -\frac{d}{ds}\left(s\cos\alpha\right) = -\cos\alpha 
\quad\Longrightarrow\quad \frac{dh}{ds} = -\cos\alpha 
$$

Therefore, multiplying both sides by $ds$, we get:
$$
dh = -\cos\alpha ds
$$